# OpenLayers6 Detect when cursor leaves map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-6

I want to hide a circle that is attached to the cursor when the cursor leaves the map. This circle **must** also hide when the cursor enters a `ol.control`.
In older OL versions I simply added a `mouseleave` listener to the `canvas` object, but in OL6 it is not guaranteed that a canvas exists and the propagation of those basic events seem to be stopped for all elements below `ol-viewport`.

How can I achieve this behavior in OL6?

Comment: When listening for contextmenu events I replaced the canvas by `map.getViewport().getElementsByClassName('ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent')[0]`  However in your case it might be easier to use `map.on('pointermove', ...)` and check if `event.pixel` is at the edge of the map.

Comment: But this way I can't detect if the cursor leaves by hovering a ol.control.

Answer (score 0):

You will need separate listeners for the controls.  My code for a context menu (not active on controls) looks like

```
var controlOver = false;

function setControlOver(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { controlOver = true; });
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { controlOver = false; });
}

setTimeout(function() {
    var controls = map.getViewport().getElementsByClassName('ol-control');
    for (var i=0; i<controls.length; i++) {
        setControlOver(controls[i]);
    }
    map.getControls().on('add', function(e) {
        // ????? setControlOver(e.element.getElement());
    });
}, 250);

map.getOverlays().on('add', function(e) {
    setControlOver(e.element.getElement());
});

var canvas = map.getViewport().getElementsByClassName('ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent')[0];

canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    if (!controlOver) {
        e.preventDefault();
        openContextMenu(e.x, e.y);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This gets more complicated when controls are added or removed over time. Another problem since OL6 is that I don't get any events on elements below ol-viewport.

Comment: I have a similar problem with overlays but for simplicity didn't include that here.  I added new listeners as the collection was updated, and that code is now in the example.  You could perhaps do something similar to new controls, but I'm not sure how to get the element for an indivual control.